# Принцип работы Spring и @Autowired

Tags: spring

Добрый день. Обращаюсь к вам после многочисленного прочтения статей и примеров по Spring. Сейчас активно его изучаю, но,пока никак не могу связать цепочки, когда как и что используется, точнее аннотации.
Вот есть такая строчка:

```
@Autowired
private BasicClassLookingForImpl basicClassLookingFor;
```

Сам класс BasicClassLookingForImpl помечен как @Service.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, лучше на пальцах даже объяснить, нужно ли так же создавать Bean этого класса?
Прописывать `<bean id="name" class="BasicClassLookingForImpl" />`

Я вот как раз этого понять не могу, когда необходимы эти бины? потому что и без них у меня все работает.

Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Единственный по-настоящему действенный способ понять зачем нужно что-то - это попасть в условия для которых это что-то было придумано. Да, можно и без бинов, но в проекте со 100 000 и более строк кода с DI существенно проще.

Comment: это понятно, но мне неясно, вот то что я написал, это эквивалентные значения или нет? То есть, чем мне поможет бин в 100000 строках кода? То есть, создав бин, я могу в коде уже не инициализировать переменную например необходимого класса,  а просто написать id бина и вызвать метод? например name.method();

Comment: Ну грубо говоря у вас объект`BasicClassLookingForImpl` загружается в некую "память" спринга при запуске, и когда вы добавляете переменной аннотацию `@Autowired`, то спринг подставляет в эту переменную объект из своей памяти, а не заново инициализирует.

Comment: во, то есть при этом бин создавать необязательно?

Comment: @Владислав нет, не надо. Классы аннотированые как `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component` автоматически добавляться в контекст спринга и создается бин.

Comment: а нужно ли данным переменным, помеченными аннотацией Autowired, делать геттеры и сеттеры? Просто у меня вообще странная вещь происходить, у меня каким-то образом, в методе одного класса, в нем я меняю значение переменной, у меня меняется переменная другого класса, они связаны Autowired, имена переменных одинаковые. Я уже все перепробывал(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опишу примерно как было. Со spring-ом знаком мало, но принцип везде один.

Раньше конфигурация прописывалась в xml. Т.е. в файле `spring.xml` с помощью `<bean...>` перечислялись все бины, с помощью каких-то других элементов определялось куда эти бины будут внедряться.

Потом, изрядно помучавшись с xml (так вроде и называли этот феномен - xml-hell), для облегчения и этой задачи придумали аннотации.

Если не ошибаюсь `@Service` заменяет `<beean ...>` в xml. Поэтому и работает без `<bean>`.

`@Autowired` тоже заменяет какой-то элемент spring.xml, ответственный за внедрение бинов.

Сервер приложений автоматически создаёт объект класса `BasicClassLookingForImpl` и записывает его в поле, помеченное `@Autowired`, т.е. в `basicClassLookingFor`

Надо сказать, что аннотации заменяют xml только в простейших случаях, которых тем не менее подавляющее большинство. Редко когда возникает необходимость составлять конфигурацию xml

Comment: спасибо большое )